# How to replace groups only if the group found?

Tags: regex

I need to transform strings that follow the structure:

<`3 digits`><`n digits`>[`letter`[`m digits`[`Roman number`]]][`k letters`]

to sometging like
<`3 digits`>.<`n digits`>[`(letter)`[`(m digits)`[`(Roman number)`]]][`- k letters`]

Those strings are, for example:

- "`121100`" - nothing interesting at the end
- "`121100N`" - should be transformed to "`121.100(N)`"
- "`121100N20`" - should be transformed to "`121.100(N)(20)`"
- "`121100N20VII`" - should be transformed to "`121.100(N)(20)(VII)`"
- "`121100NTAIL`" - should be transformed to "`121.100(N)-TAIL`"

I made a regexp

```
^(\d{3})(\d*)(\D)(\d*)((XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$)?(.*$)?
```

So the groups are `$1` - first 3-digit chunk, `$2` - other digits, `$3` - letter, `$4` - number after letter (if any), `$5` - Roman number (if any), `$8` - the rest of the string (if any)

Now I need to use only non-empty groups. My current substitution puts parentheses and the dash symbol no matter if anything was found:

```
$1.$2($3)($4)($5)-$8
```

So "`121100N`" - becomes "`121.100(N)()()-`" instead of wanted "`121.100(N)`". How can I put parentheses only if the group was found?

Comment: have you heard of non capturing groups? if you change `(<regex>)` to `(?:<regex>)` then it will still group with all of the properties, but wont show up as a captured group

Comment: @Austin_Anderson, I think it might be useful for backward process, but how could it help here?

Answer (score 1):

You may just have to do a second expression that searches for the empty capture groups and removes the  parentheses and the dash.

Find:

```
\(\)|-$
```

Replace:

```
replace with nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the matches off to a function, and transform your string there by checking if a match exists for that capture group. If there is no match, then output an empty string.

```js
let reg = /(\d{3})(\d*)([A-Z])(\d+)?((?:XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3}))?([A-Z]+)?/;
let strings = ["121100", "121100N", "121100N20", "121100N20VII", "121100NTAIL"];

strings = strings.map(str => {
  let match = str.match(reg);
  return (match) ? transform(match.splice(1)) : str;
});

console.log(strings);

function transform(m) {
  let p0 = m[0];
  let p1 = m[1];
  let p2 = (m[2]) ? `(${m[2]})` : '';
  let p3 = (m[3]) ? `(${m[3]})` : '';
  let p4 = (m[4]) ? `(${m[4]})` : '';
  let p5 = (m[5]) ? `-${m[5]}` : '';

  return `${p0}.${p1}${p2}${p3}${p4}${p5}`;
}
```